# C++ - Using sendto() with a basic string

Tags: c++, sendto

My current code doesn't work I can't find a way to send the `string` with `sendto()` or convert the basic `string` to a `char*` so that it works. Thanks. Here is my current code:

```
for (vector<string>::iterator it=lines.begin(); it!=lines.end(); ++it){
    if (int bytes = sendto(sockfd, *it, strlen(*it), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&server, svrlen) == -1){
        printf("Send error.");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `size()` or `length()` members to get the length of a string, and `data()` to get a pointer to the data:

```
sendto(sockfd, it->data(), it->size(), ...);
```

If you're stuck with a pre-2011 implementation, then `data()` won't exist, so use `c_str()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`*it` has type `std::string` which is not automatically convertible into a `void*` data buffer. You can however convert the `std::string` to a c-style string `char*` using the `c_str()` method.

Here is an example:

```
sendto(sockfd, (*it).c_str(), strlen((*it).c_str()), ...)
```

Comment: Although you wouldn't want to use `strlen` when the length is available in constant time.